# Autofac XML/JSON Configuration for Generic Type of Repository Pattern

Tags: autofac

I have a class BaseRepository which implements IRepository.

How would I specify it on the JSON configuration file, to register the generic types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac configuration (XML/JSON) doesn't support registering open generics.

Instead, create an Autofac module that does the open generic registration and set that up in your configuration.